# Write the combustion equation of an organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, combustion

> Write the combustion equation of the organic compound $\ce{C5H10O}$

I have no idea at all how to write the equation. Should I add $\ce{O2}$ to make it $$\ce{C5H10O + O2 → ... ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combustion is a reaction using O2 to burn the other reactant and will result in CO2 and H2O

$\ce {\_\_\ C5H10O + \_\_\ O2 -> \_\_\ CO2 + \_\_\ H2O}$

then just balance
so..

$\ce {C5H10O + 7O2 -> 5CO2 + 5H2O}$